# Why traditional turbulence theory concerns so much about statistics such as correlations?

Tags: statistics, correlation-functions, turbulence, scaling

I have been wondering why the traditional turbulence theory, e.g., Kolmogorov's 1941 theory, concerns so much about things like two-point correlations, structure functions, their scalings, and so forth. I saw somebody says that, IF you know all these statistics, then you know the entire field.

So my question is

1. What do these statistics actually tell us? How do these statistics imply the spatial structure of the field?
2. Why the scalings matter so much?
3. Is this statistical approach adopted from statistical mechanics, field theory, or some other branches of physics?

Comment: If a system is non-deterministic and/or chaotic, then knowing statistical values for various quantities allows one to still make predictions about behavior, e.g., it's like knowing the difference between the general path of a river with rapids vs the position of a leaf after some arbitrary time floating down the river.  The latter case is chaotic and non-deterministic whereas the former is easily determined.  The statistics give you the path of the river and things like the strength of the rapids on average over some range of distances along the river path.

Answer (score 1):

1. The average two point correlation tels us how large are the phenomena appearing in the flow. Theory actually shows us that turbulence quickly becomes a cascade of similar phenomena but at a smaller and smaller length scale. Turbulence is an mechanism of transferring energy from macro to micro scales much more efficient than merely diffusion. By observing correlation you can learn about the energy flow down to molecular level.
2. Scaling matters so much because of how similar are the phenomena appearing in the turbulent flow, so only things that are independent on it can make up such a fractal (self similar) structure. A dimensional analysis can be used to determine actual relations.
3. This statistical approach is a result of the question we are asking - what is actually happening in this flow? Correlation gives us a lot of information about it.

Comment: 1. Can I interpret the correlation represents (in a way) "the size of eddies"? 3. The reason I am asking the 3rd question is I am wondering if this statistical approach comes from some other physics branches, I can look them up and learn some more about it. So do you have any books/references recommend?

Comment: Also, I read Leo Kadanoff once said that K41 theory is a (or similar to) "mean field" approach, since Kolmogorov only considered mean dissipation, which leads to the so-called "anomalous scaling" issue. This got me thinking that I've been came across so many things in turbulence that are borrowed from some other fields, e.g., the RNG method.

Comment: You can interpret average correlation as a sort of function plotting "how many are eddies of a certain size are there". 
The rest - I am not sure.